# asp.net site stops normal working after executing the page

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net project. I add one new page here and on that page i call multiple stored procedure. After executing this page for some time my site stops working and continue refreshing on browser without giving any error. After restarting the server it starts work again.

```
private void GetBiometrixData()
{
    try
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
        var length = ddlsession.Items.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (ddlsession.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                if (ddlsession.Items[i].Text != "--Select--")
                {
                    data += ddlsession.Items[i].Text + ",";
                }
            }
        }
        data = data.Length > 0 ? data.Substring(0, data.Length - 1) : "";
        data = data.Trim();

        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ak"].ConnectionString;
        DateTime? FromDate = null;
        DateTime? ToDate = null;
        string session = "";
        string TrainingType = "";
        string EmployeeName = "";            
        string Course = "";
        string Batch = "";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFromDate.Text.ToString()))
        {
            string TodayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TodayDate.ToString().Trim(), format, provider);
        }
        else
            FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text.ToString().Trim(), format, provider);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtToDate.Text.ToString()))
            ToDate = null;
        else
            ToDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text.ToString().Trim(), format, provider);
        if (ddlsession.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == "--Select--")
            session = null;
        else
            session = ddlsession.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        if ((ddltrainingtype.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == "--Select Training Type--"))
            TrainingType = null;
        else
            TrainingType = ddltrainingtype.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        if ((ddlCourse.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == "--Select Course--"))
            Course = null;
        else
            Course = ddlCourse.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if ((ddlbatch.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == "--Select Batch--"))
            Batch = null;
        else
            Batch = ddlbatch.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployeeName.Text.ToString()))
            EmployeeName = txtEmployeeName.Text.ToString();

        string strStatus = "";            
        if (Session["strStatus"] != null)
        {
            strStatus = Convert.ToString(Session["strStatus"]);
        }

        DataSet dsCount = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SP_GetBiometricAttendanceReport2";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FromDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ToDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Session", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrainingType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TrainingType;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Batch;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalStudents", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    cmd.Parameters["@TotalStudents"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalPresentStudents", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    cmd.Parameters["@TotalPresentStudents"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalAbsentStudents", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    cmd.Parameters["@TotalAbsentStudents"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dsCount);
                    tblSummary.Visible = true;
                    lblTotalDrive.Text = cmd.Parameters["@TotalStudents"].Value.ToString();
                    lblTotalStudentAttended.Text = cmd.Parameters["@TotalPresentStudents"].Value.ToString();
                    lblTotalStudentAbsent.Text = cmd.Parameters["@TotalAbsentStudents"].Value.ToString();

                }
            }
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(FromDate)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ToDate)))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SP_GetBiometricAttendanceReportCount";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FromDate;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ToDate;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Session", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrainingType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TrainingType;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Batch;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeName;

                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(ds);

                        tblSummary.Visible = false;
                        GridView2.Visible = false;
                        RadGrid1.Visible = false;

                        GridView1.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        GridView1.DataBind();

                        //RadGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        //RadGrid1.Rebind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SP_GetBiometricAttendanceReport";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FromDate;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ToDate;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Session", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = session;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrainingType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TrainingType;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeName;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strStatus;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Batch;

                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(ds);

                        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        GridView2.DataBind();

                        RadGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        RadGrid1.Rebind();


                        if (strStatus == "")
                            lblResultStatus.Text = "<strong>Result of Total Students >></strong>";
                        else
                            lblResultStatus.Text = "<strong>Result of Total " + strStatus + " Students >></strong>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        //throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Dispose();
        con.Close();            
    }

}
```

Please help me to resolve this why site stops normal working and need to restart the server again and again.

Thanks...

Comment: where you have hosted your site ?

Comment: I've hosted it on window server, and sql version is 2014

Comment: This happened to me on shared hosting.

Comment: Win Server 2008, C2D 4GB